# Tidy evaluation programming with dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, nse

I try to write a simple function wrapping around the dplyr::case_when() function. I read the *programming with dplyr* documentation on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html but can't figure out how this works with the case_when() function.

I have the following data:

```
data <- tibble(
   item_name = c("apple", "bmw", "bmw")
)
```

And the following list:

```
cat <- list(
   item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit",
   item_name == "bmw" ~ "car"
)
```

Then I would like to write a function like:

```
category_fn <- function(df, ...){
   cat1 <- quos(...)
   df %>%
     mutate(category = case_when((!!!cat1)))
}
```

Unfortunately `category_fn(data,cat)` gives an evaluation error in this case.  I would like to obtain the same output as the output obtained by:

```
data %>% 
   mutate(category = case_when(item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit",
                               item_name == "bmw" ~ "car"))
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: This should work out of the box, there's a GitHub issue for it: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3133. For now, use one of the alternatives suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote each element of your list first:

```
cat <- list(
  quo(item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit"),
  quo(item_name == "bmw" ~ "car")
)
```

Your function does not then have to quote the cat object itself. I have also changed the use of the "everything else" ... argument to refer to the category argument explicitly in the call:

```
category_fn <- function(df, categories){
  df %>%
    mutate(category = case_when(!!!categories))
}
```

The output of the function is then as expected:

```
category_fn(data, cat)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  item_name category
      <chr>    <chr>
1     apple    fruit
2       bmw      car
3       bmw      car
```

For completeness, I note that the category list works with your function when defined using the base R quote() function too:

```
cat <- list(
  quote(item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit"),
  quote(item_name == "bmw" ~ "car")
)
> cat
[[1]]
item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit"

[[2]]
item_name == "bmw" ~ "car"

> category_fn(data, cat)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  item_name category
      <chr>    <chr>
1     apple    fruit
2       bmw      car
3       bmw      car
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.  But is there any way to get around writing the word `quo` for each item in the list?  My naive approach was to try to define `quolist <- function(...) { lapply(X = list(...), FUN = quo) }`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, the code used in the original question does not yield an error message anymore.

Answer (score 8):

**1) pass list** Using `let` from the wrapr package and `data` and `cat` from the question this works without modifying the inputs in any way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(wrapr)

category_fn <- function(data, List) {
  let(c(CATEGORY = toString(sapply(List, format))),
      data %>% mutate(category = case_when(CATEGORY)),
      subsMethod = "stringsubs",
      strict = FALSE)
}
category_fn(data, cat) # test
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  item_name category
      <chr>    <chr>
1     apple    fruit
2       bmw      car
3       bmw      car
```

**1a)** Using tidyeval/rlang and `data` and `cat` from the question:

```
category_fn <- function(data, List) {
  cat_ <- lapply(List, function(x) do.call("substitute", list(x)))
  data %>% mutate(category = case_when(!!!cat_))
}
category_fn(data, cat)
```

giving same result as above.

**2) pass list components separately** If your intention was to pass each component of `cat` separately instead of `cat` itself then this works:

```
category_fn <- function(data, ...) eval.parent(substitute({
   data %>% mutate(category = case_when(...))
}))

category_fn(data, item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit",
                   item_name == "bmw" ~ "car") # test
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  item_name category
      <chr>    <chr>
1     apple    fruit
2       bmw      car
3       bmw      car
```

**2a)** If you prefer tidyeval/rlang then this case is straight forward:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

category_fn <- function(data, ...) {
   cat_ <- quos(...)
   data %>% mutate(category = case_when(!!!cat_))
}

category_fn(data, item_name == "apple" ~ "fruit",
                   item_name == "bmw" ~ "car") # test
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another tidyverse centric approach

```
cat <- tribble(
    ~name, ~category,
    "apple", "fruit",
    "bmw", "car"
) %>% 
    str_glue_data("item_name == '{name}' ~ '{category}'")

data %>% 
    mutate(category = case_when(!!! map(cat, rlang::parse_expr)))
```